Python Scapy not detecting my npcap or winpcap installation
I have a python script which imports scapy to do some network packet analysis. The first thing my script reports is "WARNING: No libpcap provider available ! pcap won't be used". Without libpcap or ncap my script will not work, so I need to solve this problem.
The minimal code to show the problem is a python file with this single line in it:
from scapy.arch.windows import *

I am running this on Windows 11, AMD64 architecture, in a Parallels VM. I have installed Python 3.8.0 and npcap 1.79. In a CMD window, I get the following output:
C:\Users\rolf> python scapytest.py
WARNING: No libpcap provider available ! pcap won't be used

To check the correct installation, I installed nmap 7.95 and ran a local scan:
C:\Users\rolf> nmap 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-07-30 14:20 W. Europe Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000026s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT    STATE SERVICE
135/tcp open  msrpc
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds

When I uninstall npcap, nmap throws an error so I know it is being used and is working. I tried installing npcap with the winpcap option and also without. Both installations give me the same python problem.
I see other people with similar problems, but no answers that help analyse the problem.
I am running out of options to check. What can I do to find out why my Python script does not seem to detect npcap on my system?

How are you uninstalling? Simple uninstall or purge? Latter is more recommended one method.

If you can afford, configure a small virtual machine and run/test your setup there.

I used the uninstaller, as I think that should also clean the registry and other stuff I might not know about. (It is already on a minimal virtual machine I created especially for this task)

The funny thing is that this setup does work when I run it on a Windows machine with intel i7 CPU. Is the Python library of scapy not compiled for AMD/Parallels?
